# Truth Tables. (If Q, then P)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> Suppose people from Tracy always tell the truth and people from
>   Livermore always lies, You meet Diego and he says,' If I came to San
>   Jose on the train, then I am from Livermore ."is it possible that
>   Diego is from Livermore?

I don't fully understand this question. If he is telling the truth, then he is from Livermore which makes him a liar?
Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. To see this, we argue by contradiction. Suppose instead, for the sake of argument, that Diego really is from Livermore. Then Diego's statement must be false. The only way to falsify a statement of the form  $P \implies Q$ is if $P$ is true but $Q$ is false. Hence, we know that the statement "Diego came to San Jose on the train" is true but the statement "Diego is from Livermore" is false. Hence, Diego is not from Livermore. But this contradicts our initial assumption that Diego IS from Livermore. Thus, we conclude that it is impossible for Diego to be from Livermore.